# Ошибка в JavaScript, throw err

Tags: javascript, node.js

Всем привет! Хотелось бы узнать почему у меня выходит ошибка!
Вот код:

```
const allowUserBotting = require('discord.js.userbot');
const client = new Discord.Client();

allowUserBotting(client);


client.login('TOKEN');
```

Выходит ошибка:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/zetdev/dsbot/uz/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js:3:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

Comment: У вас старая версия ноды. Поддержка протокола `node:` появилась в версиях 16.0.0/14.18.0 https://2ality.com/2021/12/node-protocol-imports.html#support-for-node%3A-imports

Comment: то есть что мне делать?

Comment: Либо поставить новую ноду, либо использовать большее старые версии пакетов